# Create timer(Handler) when view appears and stop it when view disappears

Tags: android, android-handler

I have been developing iOS apps for quite a time and now i have switched to android. I have a requirement in which I have to start timer(In think in Android, I need to use handler) when view appears(onResume) and invalidate timer(stop handler) when view disappears(onPause). I am able to create runnable Handler but not able to stop it.
My code is:

```
     protected void AutoRefresh() {
     try{
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                     public void run() { 
                          new LongOperation().execute("");
                         }
                         AutoRefresh();

                 }, 60000);
    }
        catch(Exception ex){

        }

}
```

Now, how can I stop this this handler thread when view disappears. Please also comment, if its not the right way to do timer implementation in android.

Comment: There is a class in Android TimerTask. use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when view appears(onResume) and invalidate timer(stop handler) when
>   view disappears(onPause). I am able to create runnable Handler but not
>   able to stop it.

Keep a reference to the `Runnable` you use:

```
private Runnable mRefresh = new Runnable() {
     public void run() { 
          new LongOperation().execute("");
     }
     AutoRefresh();
}
//...
protected void AutoRefresh() {
    handler.postDelayed(mRefresh, 60000);
}
```

and in `onPause` remove it like this:

```
handler.removeCallbacks(mRefresh);
```

Keep in mind that this will not remove the currently `Runnable` that is being executed(if any) so  in the `LongOperation`'s `onPostExecute` method you might want to check if the `Activity` is still available before refreshing the UI or doing any other interaction with the `Activity`.

> Please also comment, if its not the right way to do timer
>   implementation in android.

You seem to need to do an action at a certain interval of time and using a `Handler` is the way to do it, I don't think a timer is what you need.